# Scala Actor not working as expected

Tags: scala, actor

I am trying to get an Actor to work but it only works partially.

MyActor goes to work every second and runs a Job by calling itself in a loop.

This part works fine.

I'd also like to call MyActor randomly from other parts of my application.

This does NOT work.

MyActor increments its mailboxSize but then continues with the loop and never fetches any of the messages sent from outside.

```
case class DoJob(fast:Boolean)

object MyActor extends Actor {

  def act = {
    loop {
      MyActor ! DoJob(false)
      receive {
        case DoJob(fast) => {
          Job.perform(fast)
        }
      }
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }
}
```

The following does not work in terms of calling DoJob(true) but merely increments MyActor's mailbox size:

```
MyActor ! DoJob(true)
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: You did call `.start` on it, right?

Comment: Yes I did, would the loop work otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each call to `receive` only gets one message.  Since you send yourself one message right before calling receive you will never reduce the mailbox size in that loop.

You should make a separate thread to send the heartbeat, or use `receiveWithin` and a `TIMEOUT` case.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Let's say I make a separate Thread, will the Actor see any concurrency issues in terms of the Job.perform(fast) method being called again from somewhere BEFORE it has finished?

Comment: @getagrip I'm pretty sure that by "separate thread", Ben means "separate actor".